# How to use position fixed on elements inside smooth scrollbar plugin's 'data-scrollbar' attribute

Tags: css, scrollbar

I am trying to create a fixed nav menu inside the smooth scrollbar plugin 'data-scrollbar'  attribute https://idiotwu.github.io/smooth-scrollbar/

Position fixed does not work

Below is an example of my HTML structure - Note that if I move the nav outside of .scroll position fixed works but I cannot scroll content if cursor positioned over nav

I'm trying to understand why this is happening and if there is a solution?

```
<div class="scroll" data-scrollbar>

    <nav></nav>

    <!-- scroll content -->

</div><!-- End of Scroll Class -->
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit late, but hopefully this helps.

You need to add a scroll listener, and apply offsets to the fixed element.

**HTML**

```
<div class="scroll" data-scrollbar>

    <nav class='fixed-nav'></nav>

    <!-- scroll content -->

</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
const fixedElem = document.getElementsByClassName('fixed-nav')[0]

const scrollbar = Scrollbar.init(
  document.getElementsByClassName('scroll')[0]
)

scrollbar.addListener( status => {
  const offset = status.offset
  
  fixedElem.style.top = offset.y + 'px'
})
```